# org-noter vs org-remark: which is best for note taking?

Tags: org-mode

I'm having a hard time choosing a note taker tool for orgmode.
Would be great to have an experienced opinion of somebody who has been using both to stress their pros and cons.
Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what these are for, but Emacs SE is not meant for opinion-based discussions of competing software packages. Something like the emacs channel on reddit is probably your best bet.

Comment: It's not about choosing the best but the best for my needs, that is why I need users telling me what each is best at doing.